# Move/copy SQL Server 2005 full text index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

We are moving our database server to a bigger box. I have several databases with full text indexes. What is the best way to move the full text indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find backup and restore is the only reliable way to move databases. The FTS should move with it when you do that. Detaching and reattaching databases never really sits well with me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving the databases, move the folders that contain the FTS information and you should be fine.

If you're doing a restore, you should be fine as is.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt was to copy over the database files and reattach them. I ran into the following error when attempting to access the catalog:

**Full-text catalog '*database name*' is in an unstable state. Drop and re-create this full-text catalog. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7624**

My second and **Successful** attempt was to restore the database from backup as Craig suggested. My catalog did come over but I received the following error:

**Property IsAccentSensitive is not available for FullTextCatalog '[CatalogName]'" This property may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)**

After a quick google search I found the answer
[MS KB 910067](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910067)

Simply detach and reattach the database and I was fine.